# Can I mount a bitlockered volume at boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount, encryption, fstab

At boot (talking about Xubuntu here), I'm already asked for the decryption key for the `/` mount point (for the OS itself), which is set up with `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab`. The current setup is having a `/boot`, a LUKS-encrypted `/`, and a Bitlocker-encrypted Windows partition.
Currently I can mount the bitlockered partition with these lines:

```
sudo dislocker -vu /dev/sdXY /media/user/windows
sudo ntfs-3g /media/user/windows/dislocker-file /media/user/windows
```

Can I use somehow the `crypttab` and `fstab` to unlock a `/dev/sdXY` device with `dislocker`, so I'm asked for the key the same way at boot?

Answer (score 1):

## Try this edit to `fstab`

Backup `/etc/fstab` by making a copy:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.original
```

Edit `/etc/fstab` and add the following lines

```
# Windows' NTFS Disk C:/
/dev/sdXY   /media/user/windows fuse.dislocker  recovery-password=000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000   0   0
/media/user/windows/dislocker-file /media/user/windows  auto    nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=C:   0   0
```

`/dev/sdXY` is the bitlocker encrypted partition. X can be a, b, c, etc. Y can be 1, 2, 3, etc.

You will need to use your own recovery password instead of a bunch of zeros.

Source: https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/issues/131

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

## Try this in fstab

```
# /dev/sdxY Windows partition
/dev/sdxY /mnt/Windows fuse.dislocker recovery-password=000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000 0 0
/mnt/Windows/dislocker-file /mnt/Data   auto    nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=C:   0   0
```

Change the Windows partition name, mount points and recovery-password as necessary.

Then `sudo mount -a` to test if it works.

Answer (score 0):

edit `/etc/crypttab`

```
# <target name> <source device>     <key file>  <options>
```

example

```
OS /dev/nvme0n1p2 /home/{user}/keys/OS.key bitlk
```

put your recovery key inside key-file,
reboot